# How to add @click event to the Buefy image

Tags: vue.js, events, vuejs2, buefy

How can I add @click event to the [Buefy image](https://buefy.org/documentation/image/) component?

This is my code which does not work (event is not fired):

```html
<div class="is-flex is-align-items-center">
  <b-image class="filelist-item-image" :src="file.thumb" @click.prevent="showPlayer(file)" />
  <div class="ml-4">
    <h2>{{ file.name }}</h2>
    <b-tag>{{ file.width }}x{{ file.height }}</b-tag>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly isn´t working?

Comment: It does not trigger the event handler at all.

Comment: Okay, but what does that mean? Is there an error? Is the event triggered but the function don´t work? You need to provide more information.

Comment: It does nothing. no error no console log nothing.

Comment: When I add it to other element for test it works.

Comment: According to the docs you can simply add events like meantioned in [#scrset](https://buefy.org/documentation/image/#srcset). So if you add it to another element and it works, while not passing `file` there, thats a different case for me.

Comment: Ok the ansver is @click.nativ so I leave it on the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://buefy.org/documentation/image/#api-view) `b-image` component has no `click` event declared (which means the component itself does not fire any `click` event).

You are trying to listen for a [**native** `click` event on the component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) so you need to bind it like this: `@click.native="..."`

**Note**

This is needed only when using Vue 2 and the `native` modifier [must be removed](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-on-native-modifier-removed.html#v-on-native-modifier-removed) if you ever upgrade to Vue 3